# How to automate a test to check if failed malloc's are handled properly?

Tags: c, makefile, automated-tests

How can I make an automated test that will check if my programs handle a failed malloc() properly? I'm using cmake and make to build. I'm already testing for functionality but I have no tests when something like malloc() returns NULL.

Comment: link with a dummy malloc that always returns `NULL`, or returns `NULL` after a few allocations.

Answer (score 1):

It is usually operating system specific.

On Linux (and most Unix-like systems) [`malloc(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) uses some [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) extending the virtual address space, such as [`mmap(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html). Then you can use [`setrlimit(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) with `RLIMIT_AS` to limit such calls (and when `mmap` fails, `malloc` will fail with `ENOMEM`).

In practice, you'll first disable [memory overcommitment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_overcommitment), then you'll use the [bash builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html) `ulimit` (with `-v`) in the shell running your tests.